# Why does DebugView not show debugging messages when Visual Studio does

Tags: debugging, internet-explorer, bho, debugview

I am developing a Browser Helper Object running inside Internet Explorer. I am writing debugging messages with `ATLTRACE("...");` These appear fine when Visual Studio is attached to the `iexplore.exe` process, but this is slow for a quick test. DebugView captures nothing from my BHO.

**Why does DebugView not show BHO debug messages?** Is it something to do with Internet Explorer running at low integrity level?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that you're running IE on Vista or later (which it sounds like since you're talking about integrity levels), you can set the integrity level of DebugView to a lower integrity so any application can send messages to it:

```
icacls dbgview.exe /setintegritylevel low
```

And if you don't like the idea of permanently setting dbgview to low integrity (it might make saving logs and whatnot a bit of a pain, as they will only go into the low-integrity store) you can run a particular instance of dbgview at low integrity using Sysinternals' `psexec` tool:

```
psexec -l dbgview
```

Finally, if all you're worried about is the amount of time that it takes to load up the VS debugger to attach to the process, you can use a command line debugger (like ntsd.exe or cdb.exe).  Ntsd.exe comes with Windows, but a newer version comes with the ["Debugging Tools for Windows" package](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/), which also includes the very similar cdb.exe.

Comment: This sounds odd, do you have any more details on why this would work?  Tracing uses OutputDebugString, not messaging.

Comment: My recollection is that OutputDebugString uses a shared memory section with a mutex and events to pass the data around.  I assume (possibly incorrectly) that opening a shared section or signaling events from a low integrity process to a higher integrity process is blocked.

Comment: Gave psexec a go - works great. Vaguely recollect similar issues in the past I'd forgotten how I solved. Running DbgView at low does the job, but rather annoying!

Time-wise, its Visual Studio loading IE symbols that's taking the time. I could probably speed it up a bit.

Comment: If you don't need the symbols, you can disable automatic symbol loading, and then just load them lazily as you need them, if you need them.

Comment: If you use the icacls method and have DbgView.exe pinned to the Windows 7 taskbar, you'll get an annoying Security Warning every time you launch it. Another reason to favour the psexec method (or wish that DbgView was updated to handle capturing low-IL messages properly by itself).

Answer (score 1):

For your quick tests, is Visual Studio still running?  If so, that might cause this problem.

Comment: I follow your line of thinking - Visual Studio is running, but not debugging.

Comment: Just to confirm: just running Visual Studio DOES intercept the messages and stops them from being visible in DebugView. It is NOT enough to just not run a debug session in it. As a workaround, it seems that if you start DebugView before visual studio, it still shows all the messages.